# React-rails- Invariant Violation: traverseParentPath(...): Cannot traverse from and to the same ID Error in setState

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, react-rails

```
require('./SliderBox');
 window.FullPage = React.createClass({
 propTypes: {

items:   React.PropTypes.object,

},
getInitialState:function(){

   return{
   layout : [],
   items: []
 }
 },
leaveBox : function(){


var newItem = this.state.layout[this.state.index];
//ar newItems = this.state.items.push(newItem);
var newIndex = this.state.index + 1;
this.setState({items:this.state.items.concat(newItem) ,index :     newIndex })

},


   getLayout : function(){
  $.ajax({
    url:"url.com",
    headers: { 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*' },
    type:'GET',
    dataType: 'json',
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    success: function(data) {
      this.setState({layout: data});

      this.setState({items :this.state.items.concat(data[0]), index: 1 })
    }.bind(this),
    error: function(xhr, status, err) {
      console.error(this.props.url, status, err.toString());
    }.bind(this)
  });
},
componentWillMount:function(){
  this.getLayout();



},
componentDidMount: function(){


  },
 loadMoreContents:function(){
  var url = "SomeLink.com"
 },
handleLeave : function(){
   this.leaveBox();
},
render: function(){
  var j = 1;
  var k = 0;
    if(this.state.index != 1){
        var sliderItems  = this.state.items.map(function(item){
        return(
        <div> <SliderBox      key={item.position}
                              title={item.name}
                              url={ "url"
                              exit= {this.handleLeave.bind(this)}
                              first= {k}
       /> </div> )
      },this);
      return(
        <div> {sliderItems} </div>
      )
    }else {
      if(this.state.layout.length > 0 ){
      return(<div> <SliderBox key={this.state.layout[0].position}
                            title={this.state.layout[0].name}
                            url={ "url"}
                            exit= {this.handleLeave.bind(this)}
                            first= {j}

     />
  </div>
 )}else
 {
   return(<div></div>)
 }
 }
 }
});
 module.exports = FullPage;
```

So basically my error comes at the this.setState , please help thanks.The traverse path error occurs only when i Integrate with Rails. it works perfect with normal react. wHile using react-rails this error occurs